# Parse Value in a Nested Json using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a nested json below , I want to parse it using JsonSlurper would like to extract the values for testName and runStatus

```
{
    "totalNumberOfRecord": 1,
    "totalPages": null,
    "testExecutionDTO": [{
        "executionId": "05f87d78-2273-4fc7-b8a9-64e4f702e62b",
        "testName": "demo",
        "runStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "testStatus": "PASS",
        "startTime": "1988-01-20 21:39:31",
        "endTime": "1988-01-20 21:42:05"
    }]
}
```

here is what I tried

```
def testExecStatus = jsonResponse.toString()
        println(testExecStatus)
        def runStatus = new JsonSlurper().parseText(testExecStatus)
        println(runStatus.runStatus)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract value from the first (index zero)  element of an array, so you should use this syntax

```
  result.testExecutionDTO[0].runStatus
```

below a complete script to reproduce

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def jsonTxt = '''
{
    "totalNumberOfRecord": 1,
    "totalPages": null,
    "testExecutionDTO": [{
        "executionId": "05f87d78-2273-4fc7-b8a9-64e4f702e62b",
        "testName": "demo",
        "runStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "testStatus": "PASS",
        "startTime": "1988-01-20 21:39:31",
        "endTime": "1988-01-20 21:42:05"
    }]
}
'''

def result =  jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonTxt)

println result.testExecutionDTO[0].runStatus
```

result is

`COMPLETED`